# handling if statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

following is the example of the code:

```
if test = "true":
    print "hello"
elif test = "false":
    pass
else:
    print "Error"
```

In above code if test = "false" ,it will print "Error", but i want code to print nothing if test = "false" and exit

I tried with "continue" instead of "pass" , still the same. Can any one help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us real code and input that actually demonstrate the problem. The code you've posted has syntax errors that would prevent it from running at all, and if you fix those, it doesn't do what you're saying it does.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing values but assigning them in your code.
Use '==' to compare values. Using single "=" will return in assigning a value, and it will be a syntax error when using with `if`

Assuming that `test` is a string.
So instead of :

```
if test = "true":
    print "hello"
elif test = "false":
    pass
else:
    print "Error"
```

Do this:

```
if test == "true":
    print "hello"
elif test == "false":
    pass
else:
    print "Error"
```

If `test` is a boolean, use:-

```
if test == True:
```

Or better simply:

```
if test:
```

Comment: Sorry typing mistake, i have use "==" in my code. And  "test" is a string not Boolean .

Comment: then check the value of `test`